# Ionic Framework Image Size

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i create a sample app using objective c on an IOS App. Displaying image on native app is correct, it displays the correct image size based on what the designer gives me. However, 1 day of programming in objective c, i decided to switch to ionic my problem is now the image is too big (i'm using the same image) not the same when I display image using objective c. By the way I did not specify and width or height both on ionic and objective c.

What seems to be the problem on the image size on ionic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used Objective C but I have been using the Ionic framework for couple applications. It is rather difficult for me to pinpoint an exact cause of the issue but I did have some cases when the images won't fit as expected while using the Ionic.

For any images used under the framework, just make sure to put the size of the images; otherwise, you will see unexpected sizes. Simply inserting  should fit within the page as expected.